# IIS 10 Coldfusion 11 served website won't load default home page on IOS mobile devices

Tags: ios, mobile, coldfusion, default, iis-10

Have a Windows 2016 server with IIS 10 running ColdFusion 11.  Certain websites (with https://) won't load the default home page on iPhone and iPad only.  The default home pages load great on all browsers on Windows 10, and even on a Mac in Safari and Chrome, but won't load on iPhone and iPad in either Safari or Chrome -- they just time out.  If I put the name of the default page in the URL, it will load just fine on these IOS mobile devices, but if I just use the site's domain name, it will NOT load.  IOS versions are up-to-date.  If we set the default page to an html page it WILL load; if we set it to a cfm page it WILL NOT load.

So the FAILING situation is in loading default cfm page on iPhone or iPad.

Appreciate any assistance or advice.  Thanks.

Comment: Are the failing requests reaching your IIS server? Assuming they are, what do the logs show for those requests?

Comment: Yes.  Lots of lines like this:  "2017-04-26 20:49:32 216.241.173.148 GET / - 443 - 72.174.230.114 Mozilla/5.0+(iPad;+CPU+OS+10_3_1+like+Mac+OS+X)+AppleWebKit/603.1.30+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/10.0+Mobile/14E304+Safari/602.1 - 200 0 64 65"

Comment: Many of these lines over a period of 3 minutes 28 seconds.

Comment: sc-win32-status=64 is indicating the problem I think.

Comment: That log example appears to be a "200 OK" response over SSL. Are those requests then being handed over to ColdFusion? Anything in the ColdFusion/connector logs?

Comment: Nothing in the ColdFusion logs.

Comment: This problem does not occur with IIS 6 on an earlier server operating system.  Only with IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: The part that doesn't make sense is that it works fine for all other browsers except on iOS devices. The only idea I have is to compare the IIS logs between a good request from a desktop browser and a failed request from iOS device. I would also do the same comparison from the browser network tools to compare the HTTP headers for differences.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a workaround for this problem.

I created an index.html file containing:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://domainname.com/index.cfm'" />
```

and made index.html the default page for the website.

I don't like it, but it seems to get things working on the iPad and iPhone.